# How to mass install/register software licences on windows systems?

Tags: windows, networking, deployment, installation

Say I have 100 new laptops that come pre-installed with windows 8.1, antivirus and microsoft office. I purchase 100 licence keys for both antivirus and office. Is there a way to automate the licence key process through networking rather than having to manually enter each key on every machine?

Comment: For MS products: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/activation/existing-customers/product-activation.aspx  Antivirus is vendor-dependent. Edit: This might not help with preinstalled Office versions.

Comment: Are we talking about a volume licensed install for Windows/Office. If so, KMS activation would be your best bet. Otherwise, you're probably better off deploying an image with volume keys...and as SvW said, antivirus is a "it depends".

Answer (score 1):

As Nathan C said in the comments, this depends.

For Office:

- Some OEM installs (Dell in particular) detect the license key in the the BIOS.  I'm going to assume you don't have one of these.
- You can use KMS activation and/or write a scripted install with a [transform file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178960(v=office.15).aspx) that you push out through AD.  This is what I'd recommend.  (Volume licensing is your friend.)

For Antivirus:

- If you purchase a centralized management console--which I highly recommend you do--this can manage your licensing.  Examples include Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager and McAfee's ePolicy Orchestrator.  Otherwise, you'll have to treat it like unmanaged software.

For unmanaged software:

Everyone does their licensing different.  If you can figure out where they store their license information, you can get around typing an install key on 100 machines.  (I had 5,000.)  Sometimes you can find the relevant keys in the registry for scripting, or use VBScript's SendKey function to throw keystrokes into a window.  You said your software was pre-installed but unlicensed, but for future installs you might want to check out [this link on silent install switches](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php).

It's hard to be more specific without more details from you, sorry.  Good luck!